# Solidus Datashift type_cast_from_database method undefined

Tags: activerecord, spree, solidus, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using solidus with rails5.
I want a feature in my site to bulk import my product with all the associations.
I found out that there is a gem datashift_solidus that is here for this purpose.

After figuring out how to use it, I was getting an error.

```
undefined method `type_cast_from_database' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007f995293a420>
```

After researching I was able to figure out that when this gem was written there was rails4 going on and this function is compatible with ActiveRecord version 4 but not version5.

Is there a way I can make it work. If so then it will be real convenient.

I am not sure if there is any kind of hack available to fix this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing to the `cast` method worked for me in Rails 5.2.

[issue link](https://github.com/kollegorna/active_hash_relation/issues/21)